# PyQt5 aplicar QgraphicsBlurEffect.performancehint y cambiar posicion del efecto DropShadow

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

**Buenas noches.**

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación con PyQt.Un colega me compartio la siguiente instruccion `self.shadow.BlurHint(QGraphicsBlurEffect.PerformanceHint)`. Esto para mejorar el rendimiento de la aplicación al ejecutar el effecto Blur.

**¿Como puedo comprobar que funciona?**

Aqui les dejo el codigo que he realizado hasta ahora. y como una pregunta mas,
**Como puedo mover la posición del efecto DropShadow**, es decir para que quede a un lado de la ventana principal.

## Codigo:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication ,QLabel, QGraphicsEffect, QVBoxLayout, QGraphicsDropShadowEffect, QGraphicsBlurEffect
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui

class Pinricpal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.resize(600,400)
        self.shadow = QGraphicsBlurEffect(self) #Efecto blur
        self.shadow.setBlurRadius(25)
        self.shadow.BlurHint(QGraphicsBlurEffect.PerformanceHint) #Instrucción que desconozco su funcionamiento 

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, True)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)

        self.sombra = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect() #Efecto de Sombra al que deseo cambiar la posición. 
        self.sombra.setBlurRadius(12)
        self.sombra.setColor(QColor(33,0,248))
        self.sombra.setOffset(2,2)

        self.setGraphicsEffect(self.shadow)
        self.setGraphicsEffect(self.sombra)

    def paintEvent(self, event=None):
        painter = QPainter(self)

        painter.setOpacity(0.7)
        painter.setBrush(QColor(168,34,3))
        painter.setPen(QColor(168,34,3))
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())

    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.dragPosition = event.globalPos() - self.frameGeometry().topLeft()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self,event):
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.move(event.globalPos() - self.dragPosition)


app = QApplication([])
principal = Pinricpal()
principal.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: ¿que significa que quede aun lado de la ventana?, prueba con `self.sombra.setOffset(-10, -10)`

Comment: si funciono el codigo,

Comment: sabras si aplique bien esta instrucción ´self.shadow.BlurHint(QGraphicsBlurEffect.PerformanceHint)´

Comment: sabras si aplique bien esta instrución self.shadow.BlurHint(QGraphicsBlurEffect.PerformanceHint)

Comment: Usa `self.shadow.setBlurHints(QGraphicsBlurEffect.PerformanceHint)`